# scrapy scraped data contains javascript

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a data from 
http://virtuacareers.com/new-jersey/staff-nurse/jobid3462987-registered-nurse-%28rn%29-jobs

and I want to get the link from this page but when I looked at my csv file, the link is:

```
javascript:GetApplyClickCount('https://careers-virtua.icims.com/jobs/5587/1024245/job?apply=yes&hashed=58168622', 'http://virtuacareers.com/list.aspx?state=voorhees&category=staff+nurse&jobtitle=registered+nurse+(rn)&jobid=3025458&dmaid=1286&dmaname=voorhees', 'SameWindow', 'scrollbars=1, toolbar=1, resizable=1, location=1, directories=1, status=1, menubar=1, copyhistory=1, fullscreen=1', 'true', '0', '0', 'virtuacareers.com', '', '', '3025458', 'Registered Nurse (RN)','212','True','','False');
```

what I only want to get is the:

```
https://careers-virtua.icims.com/jobs/5587/1024245/job?apply=yes&hashed=58168622
```

what should I do with these? this is my code for this

```
linker = hxs.select('//div[@class="box jobDesc"]/a')
item ["link"] = linker.select('@href').extract()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to extract the url using regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "javascript:GetApplyClickCount('https://careers-virtua.icims.com/jobs/5587/1024245/job?apply=yes&hashed=58168622', 'http://virtuacareers.com/list.aspx?state=voorhees&category=staff+nurse&jobtitle=registered+nurse+(rn)&jobid=3025458&dmaid=1286&dmaname=voorhees', 'SameWindow', 'scrollbars=1, toolbar=1, resizable=1, location=1, directories=1, status=1, menubar=1, copyhistory=1, fullscreen=1', 'true', '0', '0', 'virtuacareers.com', '', '', '3025458', 'Registered Nurse (RN)','212','True','','False');"
>>> re.search("\'(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)\'", s).group("url")
'https://careers-virtua.icims.com/jobs/5587/1024245/job?apply=yes&hashed=58168622'
```

In your case it would be:

```
link = linker.select('@href').extract()[0]
item ["link"] = re.search("\'(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)\'", link).group("url")
```

Comment: There occurred an error
exceptions.TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: Try `item ["link"] = re.search("\'(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)\'", link[0]).group("url")`